# What does "stackexchange" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does *stack* mean a pile? If so, is it used as a metaphor for exchanging information? If, again, so then what is it about a pile that makes it, but not a box, a metaphor for information exchange?

Answer (score 11):

The original site on the "Stack Exchange" network was "Stack Overflow", a site dedicated to answering technical questions.   The name is a humorous reference to a computer condition called a "stack buffer overflow" where a process writes outside of its allocated memory and potentially causes the process to crash.

In this context, "stack" refers to the section of computer memory allocated for a particular computer process, and is (somewhat) different from the more common use of "stack" to refer to an organized *pile* of objects.

[More information on computer *stacks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))

As a noun, an "exchange" is a place where goods or ideas are transferred or sold.  A good example is the New York Stock Exchange, where, every day, millions (or perhaps billions) of *shares* in publicly traded companies are bought and sold.

The combined phrase "stack exchange" has no real meaning.  Instead it's a [concatenation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concatenate) of "Stack Overflow" and a reference to the *exchange* of questions and answers on a wide variety of subjects.